How to normalize variable font weights (10-218) to standard CSS weights (100-900) in Tailwind CSS?
The Problem
I have a project using multiple fonts, including a variable font that uses an unusual weight scale (10-218) alongside regular fonts that use the standard CSS weight scale (100-900).
Currently, I'm forced to use two different Tailwind classes for each text element because of this mismatch:
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'N27': ['N27','Arial', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif'],
        'Chopin': ['Chopin', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif'],
      },
      fontWeight: {
        'Chopin-thin': '10',
        'Chopin-light': '75',
        'Chopin-normal': '125',
        'Chopin-medium': '150',
        'Chopin-semibold': '175',
        'Chopin-bold': '200',
        'Chopin-black': '218',
      },
    }
  }
}

This leads to verbose markup like:
<!-- Regular font -->
<p class="font-N27 font-bold">Normal font bold text</p>

<!-- Variable font requiring special weight class -->
<p class="font-Chopin font-Chopin-bold">Chopin font bold text</p>

What I Want
I want to be able to use standard font-weight classes (font-bold, font-medium, etc.) with both fonts, having the variable font automatically map its native 10-218 scale to the standard 100-900 scale.
Ideally, I'd like to write:
<p class="font-N27 font-bold">Normal font bold text</p>
<p class="font-Chopin font-bold">Chopin font bold text</p>

And have the browser understand that font-bold means 700 for the regular font but 200 for the Chopin font.
Question
Is there a way to normalize these different weight scales in Tailwind CSS, perhaps using CSS custom properties or some other technique, so I can use standard font-weight classes with both fonts?
Additional Context

The variable font's weight range is 10-218
Other fonts in the project use standard weights (100-900)
Using Tailwind CSS v3.x

Update: Current Solution
I found a way to solve this using Tailwind plugins, but I'm looking for feedback on whether there's a more elegant approach:
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'N27': ['N27','Arial', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif'],
        'Chopin': ['Chopin', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif'],
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    function({ addBase }) {
      addBase({
        // Define the weight mapping for Chopin font
        ':root': {
          '--font-weight-thin-chopin': '10',
          '--font-weight-extralight-chopin': '45',
          '--font-weight-light-chopin': '75',
          '--font-weight-normal-chopin': '125',
          '--font-weight-medium-chopin': '150',
          '--font-weight-semibold-chopin': '175',
          '--font-weight-bold-chopin': '200',
          '--font-weight-extrabold-chopin': '210',
          '--font-weight-black-chopin': '218',
        },
        // Apply weight mappings conditionally based on font family
        '.font-Chopin': {
          '&.font-thin': { fontWeight: 'var(--font-weight-thin-chopin)' },
          '&.font-extralight': { fontWeight: 'var(--font-weight-extralight-chopin)' },
          '&.font-light': { fontWeight: 'var(--font-weight-light-chopin)' },
          '&.font-normal': { fontWeight: 'var(--font-weight-normal-chopin)' },
          '&.font-medium': { fontWeight: 'var(--font-weight-medium-chopin)' },
          '&.font-semibold': { fontWeight: 'var(--font-weight-semibold-chopin)' },
          '&.font-bold': { fontWeight: 'var(--font-weight-bold-chopin)' },
          '&.font-extrabold': { fontWeight: 'var(--font-weight-extrabold-chopin)' },
          '&.font-black': { fontWeight: 'var(--font-weight-black-chopin)' },
        }
      })
    }
  ]
}

This solution works and allows me to use standard font-weight classes:
<p class="font-N27 font-bold">Uses weight 700</p>
<p class="font-Chopin font-bold">Uses weight 200</p>

Pros:

Maintains standard Tailwind classes
Works with both font types
Clean HTML markup

Cons:

Feels verbose in the config
Requires maintaining two separate weight scales
Not sure if this is the most maintainable approach

Is there a more elegant way to handle this? Perhaps using CSS @font-face with custom weight mappings, or some other Tailwind feature I'm missing?

Not sure if this is possible, However, if you're using a framework you could create a component that handles this logic for you.

@Reyno Thanks for the suggestion! While a component-based approach could work, I actually found a solution using Tailwind plugins that preserves the standard font-weight utility classes (I've updated my question with this temporary solution).

It seems like you don't need the CSS variables in :root and add the weight values directly in the .font-<weight> rules.

If you've paid FontFabric for a license to Chopin Variable and the wght axis uses 125 for Regular, then I would go back to them and ask for a font that implemented in conformance with the OpenType spec so that it is interoperable with CSS. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/dvaraxistag_wght: "Scale interpretation: Values can be interpreted in direct comparison to values for usWeightClass in the OS/2 table, or the CSS font-weight property. Recommended or required “Regular” value: 400 is required."
